# Copying data hidden by interface

Tags: interface, go

I have got some TCP connection which returns some data for me. Also I have got a structure that represents this data.

```
type Item struct {
  A int32
  B int32
}
```

`Item` supports `Unpacker` interface

```
func (item *Item) Unpack(data []int32) {
    item.A = data[0]
    item.B = data[1]
    return
}

type Unpacker interface {
    Unpack([]int32)
}
```

So I receive some data from Network which represents a bunch of items. Now I want to pass my structure to function and I want to get back a slice of structures filled with data:

```
func find(packet [][]int32, responseItem Unpacker) (items []Unpacker) {
    items = make([]Unpacker, len(packet))
    for i, data := range(packet) {
        responseItem.Unpack(data)
        items[i] = responseItem
    }
    return
}
```

Of course in this case I have got a slice with a number of identical items (pointers to same item). But I want to get different items and

```
items[i] = *responseItem
```

doesn't work in my case.

Here is link to playground: http://play.golang.org/p/RP4ryxoG2I

I believe I didn't understand how Go works (it is my first time with Go). And also good to be noticed: I don't want to use reflection here if it is possible.

Answer (score 1):

You've got unpacker backwards.  You want to create new `Item` in your loop, Unpack into the item and then assign into your slice.  You can do this by making `find` accept a function returning an `Unpacker`.

See the following: http://play.golang.org/p/rFoa1eoh4A

Your `find` function:

```
type UnpackerMaker func() (Unpacker)

func find(packet [][]int32, makeUnpacker UnpackerMaker) (items []Unpacker) {
    items = make([]Unpacker, len(packet))
    for i, data := range(packet) {
        unpacker := makeUnpacker()
        unpacker.Unpack(data)
        items[i] = unpacker
    }
    return
}
```

Comment: Yes, you are right. I wasn't clear enough :) I want to pass my struct (`Item` in this case) explicitly. Because protocol implementation and network job is done inside some driver (which I am writing). So user should pass structure explicitly to driver, so he will receive unpacked data to this structure.

Comment: Driver doesn't know anything about data representation. Driver receives some bytes and one pass structure so Driver could fit data to structure. For different goals one could make different network requests and will receive different responses. For each response he could define its structure.

Comment: So I can't just use `Item` in `find` (it is actually select from database). I pass Structure and Driver should use it like a pattern to unpack binary data back to user

Comment: Right, but you're unpacking into the same item repeatedly.  You'd need to **copy** the item into items, not assign it.

Comment: Yes, I am unpacking to the same Struct, but this particular Struct should be passed by developer. For example you want to fetch users form database, so you call `select(userId, &User{})` where `userId` is id to be fetched, and `User` is a structure in wich result will be unpacked.

Comment: Ohhhh, k. You want generics...They don't exist in Go.  What you should use, instead, is a func returning an `Unpacker`...

Comment: @fl00r does the function strategy do what you need?

Comment: It could. And maybe it will. The problem is a design problem. How I understand Go in my case I can only pass an interface. So I should create function on my interface that returns another "instance" of interface. Looks not good for me. I mean I should create an "instance" of interface, then pass it to func, then call a method on it which will create a new instance :). Hope you get my point. Anyway, it will work. Perhaps reflection will be better solution but I am trying to skip it for now.

Comment: Anyway, thank you for your answer and discussion. I will spent some time to think another solution and if I won't I will use yours :)

Comment: I was thinking about this and [came up with this](http://play.golang.org/p/SJcmXD4HY6) which is functionally identical! Use the function pointer solution. No need to create another interface, and you can't call a static method on an instance - that is not how go works!

Comment: @NickCraig-Wood brilliant!

Comment: Cool, first class functions rules :)